# change border color on hover and active to select element with ant design

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, antd

I would like to change the border color of Select component of ant design library

```
import { Select } from "antd";

    <Select
      mode="tags"
      style={{
        minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 500,
        margin: "1rem",
      }}
      placeholder="Catégories"
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
    />
```

I tried adding borderColor: "#ff7640" in the style property

```
import { Select } from "antd";

    <Select
      mode="tags"
      style={{
        minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 500,
        margin: "1rem",
        borderColor: "#ff7640"
      }}
      placeholder="Catégories"
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
    />
```

but it doesn't work.
The border color seems to be managed by a sub div with the class .ant-select-selector, but even by adding
I tried adding

```
.ant-select-selector:hover {
   border-color: "#ff7640"
}
```

in the css file, it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `border-width` and `border-style` and add the `className` like this:

```
   <Select
      mode="tags"
      style={{
        minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 500,
        margin: "1rem",
        borderColor: "#ff7640",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
      }}
      className="ant-select-selector"
      placeholder="Catégories"
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
    />
```

And if still there is no effect add `!important` to your `:hover` border-color code